# Change default console TERM from vt102 to xterm?

Tags: raspbian, serial, raspbian-jessie, terminal, serial-console

When connecting to the Pi by the serial console, I'd like to have the default `TERM` be `xterm`, rather than the current default of `vt102`:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ echo $TERM
vt102
pi@raspberrypi:~$ tty
/dev/ttyS0
```

I know I could add this to `.bashrc`, etc. - but I only want to change the current default, and to otherwise not impact other types of connections.

https://www.debian.org/releases/jessie/i386/ch05s03.html.en seems to indicate that I should be able to add `TERM=xterm` to the boot parameters - which are at `/boot/cmdline.txt`.  As such, I tried updating the following:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

to:

```
dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=serial0,115200 TERM=xterm console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline fsck.repair=yes rootwait
```

... and then rebooting, but with no change.  Now, http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/bootparam.7.html indicates that this may be a "(useless?) example" (for reasons I don't understand).

Now, I did find `/lib/systemd/system/serial-getty@.service`, which contains the following:

```
[Service]
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200,38400,9600 %I $TERM
```

... but I can't find where the default `$TERM` is being defined.

I did add the following here:

```
    Environment=TERM=xterm
```

This is working - but it seems that I'm still missing part of the puzzle here, as to where this is defaulting to `vt102`, or why this can't be set in `cmdline.txt`.

(Other sources I've already referenced:)

- [Colored console over serial connection?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40848/colored-console-over-serial-connection)
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198794/where-does-the-term-environment-variable-default-get-set
- https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=23194
- https://patchwork.openembedded.org/patch/71447/
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Getty

Answer (score 2):

Had I read the "Docs" section of the output from `systemctl status serial-getty@ttyS0.service`, it includes a link to http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/serial-console.html .  From there:

> serial-getty@.service is responsible for all other terminals,
>   including serial ports such as /dev/ttyS0. It differs in a couple of
>   ways from getty@.service: among other things the $TERM environment
>   variable is set to vt102 (hopefully a good default for most serial
>   terminals) rather than linux (which is the right choice for VTs only),
>   and a special logic that clears the VT scrollback buffer (and only
>   work on VTs) is skipped.

So, this is apparently a hard-coded default.  This is also supported by the following:

- http://lists.opensuse.org/opensuse-bugs/2015-07/msg01905.html
- https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/76153ad45f09b6ae45464f2e03d3afefbb4b2afe/NEWS#L6149

However, for completeness - I'm still searching for where this is actually coded.

Comment: Xterm is a vt102 terminal emulator for X windows. Your question makes no sense to me. Try another explanation.

Comment: @PaulF8080 - it is somewhat ambiguous.  In this context, maybe take it to mean that we want the terminal to "function like xterm".  See also: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/23764/changing-terminal-emulators and http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43945/whats-the-difference-between-various-term-variables ?

Comment: Xterm and the console both emulate the old DEC VT102 terminal

Comment: @PaulF8080 - sure, but xterm is supposed to be a superset of vt220 - while also supporting colors and other features.  Bottom line, a lot of things are disabled when `TERM=vt102`, but work with `TERM=xterm`.  Look at how many bashrc and such files are checking for `TERM=xterm` various things...

Comment: The vt102 does color and cursor control with ANSI escape sequences. Does that solve your problem, then?

Comment: @PaulF8080 - vt102 emulation does not support color.  Please refer to the references I included in my first reply to you above.  Even if it would, most OS distributions are configured to disable color support and related features unless `TERM=xterm` (or `xterm*` with pattern matching).  The question here is/was how to change the default `TERM` environment variable for serial console connections, not whether or not it is required (please).

Comment: I still don't get, sorry. The TERM variable has nothing to do with the serial port operation. You set it according to what's on the other end of the cable. The serial port will gladly send ANSI characters. Only software sending the text needs to look at TERM

Comment: @PaulF8080 - in this case, the Pi running Raspbian _is_ what is on the other end of the cable.  By default, when connecting to the Pi, combined with the bashrc files and such I mentioned above, it restricts itself to no colors - including the prompt, directory listings, etc. - based on `TERM=vt102` (and not being `TERM=xterm`.  Once connected to the Pi, I can send it `export TERM=xterm` to enable color support and other functionality.  _All this Q/A was intended for was how to have this properly set by default_, respecting the considerations listed.